# D3 link is not defined

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to implement a functionality where the user can filter a D3 force layout by checkbox. I tried to hack around with a few examples and finally started working with this example where the filtering is implemented using these functions:

```
function createFilter() {
        //alert("createFilter");
        d3.select(".filterContainer").selectAll("div")
          .data(["6UGSWD8D", "7V9JCFSV", "AFWXF8CH", "HTFNIQDD"])
          .enter()  
          .append("div")
          .attr("class", "checkbox-container")

          .append("label")
          .each(function (d) {
                // create checkbox for each data
                d3.select(this).append("input")
                  .attr("type", "checkbox")
                  .attr("id", function (d) {
                      return "chk_" + d;
                   })
                  .attr("checked", true)
                  .on("click", function (d, i) {
                      // register on click event
                      var lVisibility = this.checked ? "visible" : "hidden";
                      filterGraph(d, lVisibility);
                   })
                d3.select(this).append("span")
                    .text(function (d) {
                        return d;
                    });
        });
        $("#sidebar").show();
    }




function filterGraph(aType, aVisibility) {

        // change the visibility of the connection link
        link.style("visibility", function (o) {
            var lOriginalVisibility = $(this).css("visibility");
            return o.certainty === aType ? aVisibility : lOriginalVisibility;
        });

        // change the visibility of the node
        // if all the links with that node are invisibile, the node should also be invisible
        // otherwise if any link related to that node is visibile, the node should be visible
        node.style("visibility", function (o, i) {
            var lHideNode = true;
            link.each(function (d, i) {
                if (d.source === o || d.target === o) {
                    if ($(this).css("visibility") === "visible") {
                        lHideNode = false;
                        // we need show the text for this circle
                        d3.select(d3.selectAll(".nodeText")[0][i]).style("visibility", "visible");
                        return "visible";
                    }
                }
            });
            if (lHideNode) {
                // we need hide the text for this circle 
                d3.select(d3.selectAll(".nodeText")[0][i]).style("visibility", "hidden");
                return "hidden";
            }
        });
    }
```

Now, I am facing an error which says link is undefined. From my understanding it could be so because the variable link has not been defined in the scope of the function. However, both "link" and "node" have been defined inside the main function which draws the layout:

```
d3.json("graph.json", function(error, graph) {
  if (error) throw error;

var link = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "links")
      .selectAll("line")
      .data(graph.links)
      .enter().append("line")
        .attr("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.value); });    

 var node = svg.append("g")

    .attr("class", "nodes")
    .selectAll("circle")
    .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("r", 5)

//    .text(function(d) { return d.name })
      //.attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d.group); })
      .call(d3.drag()
          .on("start", dragstarted)
          .on("drag", dragged)
          .on("end", dragended));

    var text = svg.append("svg:g")
                  .selectAll("g")
                  .data(simulation.nodes())
                  .enter().append("svg:g")
                  .attr("class", "nodeText");

    // A copy of the text with a thick white stroke for legibility.
    text.append("svg:text")
        .attr("x", 8)
        .attr("y", ".31em")
        .attr("class", "shadow")
        .text(function (d) {
            return d.id;
        });



  simulation
      .nodes(graph.nodes)
      .on("tick", ticked);

  simulation.force("link")
      .links(graph.links);

  function ticked() {
    link
        .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

    node
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
  }
});
```

Is there a way to maintain the way the main function is written and at the same time using these two functions to create the filtering effect?

Comment: Move the functions to inside `d3.json`.

Comment: I tried doing that, and I also moved the method calling the function inside d3.json. There is a new error now: d3.selectAll(...)[0] is undefined

Comment: Those are different problems: after solving the scope issue, you just discovered a new problem in your code. At this point, the best idea is creating a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).